# Post multidimensional array using CURL and get the result on server

Tags: php, arrays, curl, multidimensional-array

I am sending data from my local machine to server using `CURL`. And the data is multidimensional array.

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
    )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 0
    )
[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 11
    )
)
```

I am using this below code for sending the data.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "my_url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);  // $array is my above data
```

But at server when I try to put this incoming data to file or just `print_r` it gives me this below output

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
[1] => Array
[2] => Array
)
```

But I want the output in multidimensional.

I tried with `print_r($_POST[0])` but it gives only `Array` text.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

cURL can only accept a simple key-value paired array where the values are strings, it can't take an array like yours which is an array of objects. However it does accept a ready made string of POST data, so you can build the string yourself and pass that instead:

```
$str = http_build_query($array);

...

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str);
```

A `print_r($_POST)` on the receiving end will show:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, let you know when I will integrate this in my code. I have one more question ,I tried with sending array of array but at receiving end it gives the same output `Array
(
[0] => Array
[1] => Array
[2] => Array
)`

Comment: Yes, cURL can't take an array of arrays or an array of objects, it can only take a one dimensional array of strings, unless you build the post data manually (as in the answer).

Comment: Thanks MrCode today I have implemented your code and now it is working as I wanted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I would give a go to serialize and unserialize:

1) Before sending your array, serialize it (and set your transfer mode to binary):

```
(...)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);           // need this to post serialized data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, serialize($array));  // $array is my above data
```

2) When you receive the data, unserialize it:

```
$array = unserialize($_POST);
```

More details [here](http://theodin.co.uk/blog/development/how-to-serialize-and-unserialize-post-arrays-using-php.html) and [here](http://dave.kinkead.com.au/post/3930771155/posting-serialized-data-with-curl-php)

Comment: great, but it didnt work this way, i had to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('data'=>serialize($array)));` and then `$array = unserialize($_POST['data']);`

Answer (score 3):

```
$param['sub_array'] = json_encode($sub_array);
```

and on the other side

```
$sub_array= json_decode($_POST['sub_array']);
```

Comment: Well I don't remember that whether I have tried this way. But may be useful for other users. :)